# Recurring email notification to all list entry

Tags: workflow, loop

I have a list (contains hundreds of items) which I need to send email notification for each item's creator on every end of quarter.
Is SharePoint workflow able to loop through the list and triggered on a specific date every year?

[image: My workflow flowchart]

I'm not the admin of sharepoint, I'm just a sharepoint site admin. Is there a way for me to do this?

Hopefully someone have any solution/suggestions. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you using 2013?

Comment: yes it's SharePoint 2013 on premise

Comment: currently im using 2010, but planning to use 2013 if the version support

Comment: You can use the Retention Policy : it permits to launch a workflow at a specific date. It is defined into the settings of your list. Google it to get more details!

Comment: Retention Policy is not able to WF 2013 version

Answer (score 0):

With sharepoint workflow, it is not possible. You can create a **timer job** using `client object model` in C# (`CSOM`).